# I would like to know the difference between LDAP3 Connection(auto_bind=True) and Connection().bind() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldap3

I was passing wrong credentials(password) in below code

```
conn = Connection(server, account_username, account_password, auto_bind=True)
```

and getting below error

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials
```

When I do the same without auto_bind argument in connection.

```
conn = Connection(server, account_username, account_password)
conn.bind()
```

conn was not throwing any error.
conn.bind() is False.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: auto_bind isn't a flag. According to the [docs](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html): _auto_bind: automatically opens and binds the connection. Can be AUTO_BIND_NONE, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, AUTO_BIND_TLS_AFTER_BIND, AUTO_BIND_TLS_BEFORE_BIND._. Do these work for you?

Comment: No luck, they are not helpful even with the valid password. @tdelaney

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check the edited post, I was trying to understand why Connection() method is not throwing any error when I passed a wrong password. @jwilleke

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Check error raised during the last bind in the
   `connection.last_error` field.

```py
server = ldap3.Server("LDAP_HOST", use_ssl=True)
connection = ldap3.Connection(
    server,
    "WRONG_LDAP_USERNAME",
    "WRONG_LDAP_PASSWORD"
)
connection.bind()
print(connection.last_error)
```

result

```py
invalidCredentials
```

2. Set argument `raise_exceptions=True` during initialization of the `ldap3.Conneciton`

```py
server = ldap3.Server("LDAP_HOST", use_ssl=True)
connection = ldap3.Connection(
    server,
    "WRONG_LDAP_USERNAME",
    "WRONG_LDAP_PASSWORD",
    raise_exceptions=True
)
connection.bind()
```

result

```py
dap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - None - bindResponse - None
```